# Find sequence limit of $\ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n^2+2} - \sqrt{n^2-n}$

Tags: limits

So I have this question, I keep getting 0 as an answer, but my professor manages to get $1$ as an answer for some reason which I do not understand.
Here is my working out:

$$\ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n^2+2} - \sqrt{n^2-n}$$
$$\ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n^2(1+\frac{2}{n^2})} - \sqrt{n^2(1-\frac{n}{n^2})}$$
$$\ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n^2}-\sqrt{n^2} = 0$$

My professor answering  this question:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nZWw.png)

Am I wrong or he is wrong?

Comment: Your professor is right and you are wrong. You cannot go from your second line to the third.

Comment: Welcome to the Math.SE. I don't look at the image but you have an indeterminate form like $\infty-\infty$. After for my humble opinion to solve your limit is $\lim_{n\to\infty} (\sqrt{n^2+2} - \sqrt{n^2-n})=\lim_{n\to\infty} (\sqrt{n^2+2} - \sqrt{n^2-n})\cdot \frac{(\sqrt{n^2+2} + \sqrt{n^2-n})}{(\sqrt{n^2+2} + \sqrt{n^2-n})}$...etc.

Comment: You're wrong $\lim (a-b) \neq \lim a - \lim b$ for infinite limits, therefore $\lim \sqrt{n^2(1+\frac{2}{n^2})}-\sqrt{n^2(1-\frac{n}{n^2})} \neq \lim \sqrt{n^2(1+\frac{2}{n^2})}-\lim\sqrt{n^2(1-\frac{n}{n^2})} = \lim \sqrt{n^2}-\lim\sqrt{n^2}\neq \lim \sqrt{n^2}-\sqrt{n^2}$

Comment: There are many ways of finding the limit, my best is to write $\sqrt{1+t}=1+\frac{t}{2}+O(t^2)$ as $t\to 0$.

Comment: It appears you have a typo in your comment. I think the exercise is supposed to be $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n^2+n}-\sqrt{n^2-n})$, in which case, your professor is completely correct.

Comment: @Angel In fact I have put the rounded brackets in my comment.

Comment: Replacing *a part* of an expression by its limit usually leads to wrong results. Other example: $(1+\frac1n)^n=1^n=1$ would not be correct.

Comment: Your last edit makes it worse.

Comment: @Sebastiano Good catch! But I am actually referring not to the lack of parentheses, but to the radicand. The first radicand should probably be $n^2+n$ and not $n^2+2$. I say this because the symbolic manipulations OP made match the former and not the latter, and the same goes with the manipulations the professor did. In fact, the professor explicitly wrote the radicand as $n^2+n$, which makes me believe OP made a typo.

Comment: Not a proof but a serious hint: $\sqrt{1000001000000}-\sqrt{999999000000}=1.0000000001164\cdots$.

Comment: @Angel Ahaahah :-) for the good catch. I not have seen before the solution of the professor. I have written as I solve this limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, it appears you have a typo in your stating of the question. Either that, or your professor made a typo in their solution of the question. It appears your professor solved $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n^2+n}-\sqrt{n^2-n})$$ instead. Your solution also seems to imply that this is what the question is supposed to be as well.

With that being said, your solution is wrong. You claimed $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\sqrt{n^2(1+\frac{n}{n^2})}-\sqrt{n^2(1-\frac{n}{n^2})}\bigg)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n^2}-\sqrt{n^2}),$$ which is inaccurate. You cannot "replace" $\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}}$ and $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}$ with $1$ without also "replacing" $\sqrt{n^2}$ with $\infty$. In doing what you did, you effectively just said, informally, that $0\cdot\infty=0$. What you should have done is to factor n out, leaving $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\sqrt{n^2(1+\frac{n}{n^2})}-\sqrt{n^2(1-\frac{n}{n^2})}\bigg)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\bigg(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}}\bigg)$$, with $\lim_{n\to\infty}n=\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}}\bigg)=0$, so more work is needed from here. However, this approach will actually lead nowhere, realistically. The easier approach has already been explained in the comments to your post, and is the same approach your professor used. Namely, from the beginning, you should have said $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n^2+n}-\sqrt{n^2-n})=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n^2+n}-\sqrt{n^2-n})\frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt{n^2-n}}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt{n^2-n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n^2+n)-(n^2-n)}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt{n^2-n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+\sqrt{n^2-n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}}}.$$ Now, doing the replacement of $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}$ and $\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}}$ with $1$ is actually valid, since there is no longer a $n$ term interacting with those here. Hence, the answer your professor gave is correct.

Comment: I upvoted all and all your efforts.

Comment: Why is more work needed, when in second solution the result was 0?

Comment: @FredyMercury Forgive me, but I do not know which second result you are talking about. None of the solutions in my post result in the limit you asked about being equal to 0. So I think you need to elaborate on what you mean.